# Validating data in a File Geodatabase

Tags: file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4

I am not quite sure how to ask this question...When editing data, is there a way have a File Geodatabase and say, all US states, major cities, and major roads.  When say, New York is chosen as a state, then only the major cities and major roads in New York are available. This just an example, but I guess I am trying to validate data, so when someone is editing they can't select options that aren't in their region.  Using the example above, if New York is chosen, Miami wouldn't be option.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to create dynamic domains (a domain is a drop-down list when editing in ArcGIS).  It's not possible out-of-the-box but I have seen some third-party tools that do it.  Unfortunately the third-party tool I know of, it's just part of a much much bigger toolset and the software was well over the $100k range when I looked at it.  There may be other add-ins that will do it.

Comment: The cheaper option here would be using FME to do this for you. https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/886/working-with-geodatabase-subtypes-and-domains.html has "Resolve Subtypes" and "Resolve Domains" on the geodatabase reader. "

Comment: Might be another dumb question but what is FME?

Comment: also with the "cheaper option" what is the price of that?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1